CSS grid and resize: shrink rows and columns
I found out that I can use CSS grid with resize: both on the grid items to make the grid rows and columns resizable. For example, when stretching an item wider, the width of the corresponding column expands, such that other items in the column expand also and the other columns shrink. The same works for height.
However, this only works when making items larger. When shrinking an item (making it smaller), it gets shrunk individually and the rest of the grid is not affected, leaving gaps in the layout.
Is there some way to control this behavior, such that both stretching and shrinking affects the entire grid?
Here's the snippet:


.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.container div {
  margin: 10px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
}
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
      <div>Three</div>
      <div>Four</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




Interesting, I think this is because changing the size of the div does not fundamentally change the size of the grid. The div is changing size but the 1fr remains the same. Perhaps a minmax option might be better but I'm unsure on my theory.

A) you could use auto , instead 1fr. B) you give a width of 100% to the container and it is also a block. it won't shrink below those 100% of width even if items do not fill the columns. try inline-grid or float to modify this behavior. C) as soon as you resize a block, it will keep that resized size and won'nt expand nor shrink anymore. D) put your resize and overflow on your container itself and eventually on only one child. It will be much less messy ;)

@G-Cyrillus not sure if I understand your solution, would you mind writing it up as an answer perhaps?

hello, it is not a solution for what you thought it could be, but that it could be usefull on the grid itself ;)  here is an example of the idea https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abxEjYR ;)
